# Busqueda Personalizada GridControl DevExpress en c#

Tags: c#

Hola buenos días quiero hacer una búsqueda personalizada en un gridControl es decir en la celda 0 del gridControl escribo el código del producto y me  cargue los demás datos tengo el ejemplo de como hacerlo en un datagrid aquí dejare el código para ver quizás alguien me ayuda a acoplarlo.

Evento desde el cual llamo al método buscar:

```
public void buscar_Productos(string valor)
{
     Frm_Filtro filt = new Frm_Filtro();
     Advertencia adv = new Advertencia();
     RN_Productos obj = new RN_Productos();
     DataTable dato = new DataTable();

     string _xxidProd = "";

     string _idprod;
     string _nomprod;
  double _cant = 1;
  double _precio = 0;
  double _importe = 0;
  string _und;
  string _tipoProd;
  Double _Utili_Unit;
  double descuento = 0;
  double totalDescuento = 0;
  double totalutilidad = 0;
  double stock = 0;
  double precioNormal;
  bool duplicado = false;
  int NroFila_Grid = 0;

  dato = obj.RN_Buscar_Todas_Productos(valor);
  if (dato.Rows.Count 0)
  {
      if (dato.Rows.Count == 1)
      {
          if (dato.Rows.Count 0)
          {
              _idprod = Convert.ToString(dato.Rows[0]["Id_Pro"]);
              _nomprod = Convert.ToString(dato.Rows[0]["Descripcion_Larga"]);
              _tipoProd = Convert.ToString(dato.Rows[0]["TipoProdcto"]);
              _und = Convert.ToString(dato.Rows[0]["UndMedida"]);
              _precio = Convert.ToDouble(dato.Rows[0]["Pre_vntaxMenor"]);
              _Utili_Unit = Convert.ToDouble(dato.Rows[0]["UtilidadUnit"]);
              precioNormal = Convert.ToDouble(dato.Rows[0]["Pre_vntaxMenor"]);
              stock = Convert.ToDouble(dato.Rows[0]["Stock_Actual"]);
              _importe = _precio * 1;

              //String _desc = "";
              int nIndex = buscarExistente(dgv_ven, "Codigo", valor, dgv_ven.CurrentRow.Index);

              if (nIndex == -1)
              {
                  nIndex = dgv_ven.CurrentRow.Index;
                  //agregarFila(nIndex, _idprod, _nomprod);
                  agregarFila(nIndex, _idprod.Trim(), _nomprod, _cant, _precio, _importe, _und, _tipoProd, _Utili_Unit, stock, descuento, precioNormal, totalDescuento, totalutilidad);
              }


          }
      }
      else
      {
          //MessageBox.Show("Asegurate de Buscar por el ID del Producto, para tener una Busqueda Exacta.", "Advertencia",
MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
          return;
      }

  }
  else
  {

      frm_noexiste EXIS = new frm_noexiste();
      Frm_Filtro fil = new Frm_Filtro();
      fil.Show();
      EXIS.Text = "CODIGO -" + dgv_ven.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;
      EXIS.lbl_venta.Text = "compra";
      //dgv_ven.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "";
      EXIS.ShowDialog();
      fil.Hide();



      if (EXIS.Tag.ToString() == "A")
      {

          if (EXIS.lsv_Det.Rows.Count 0)
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < EXIS.lsv_Det.Rows.Count; i++)
              {
                  if (EXIS.lsv_Det.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value != null)
                  {

                      var item = EXIS.lsv_Det.Rows[i];
                      _idprod = Convert.ToString(item.Cells[0].Value);
                      int nIndex = buscarExistente(dgv_ven, "Codigo", _idprod, dgv_ven.CurrentRow.Index);
                      if (nIndex == -1)
                      {

                          buscar_Productos(_idprod.Trim());

                      }
                  }


              }
          }
          if (EXIS.Tag.ToString() == "Si")
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < EXIS.lsv_Det.Rows.Count; i++)
              {
                  if (EXIS.lsv_Det.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value != null)
                  {

                      var item = EXIS.lsv_Det.Rows[i];
                      _idprod = Convert.ToString(item.Cells[0].Value);
                      int nIndex = buscarExistente(dgv_ven, "Codigo", _idprod, dgv_ven.CurrentRow.Index);
                      if (nIndex == -1)
                      {

                          buscar_Productos(_idprod.Trim());

                      }

                  }


              }
          }
      }
      return;
  }

}





---desde aqui llamo al evento buscar---
private void dgv_ven_CellEndEdit(object sender,
DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
try
{
  if (dgv_ven.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value != null)
  {
      if (dgv_ven.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Codigo")
      {



          string valor = dgv_ven.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

          //verificando si existe
          int nIndex = buscarExistente(dgv_ven, "Codigo", valor, e.RowIndex);
          if (nIndex >= 0)
          {
              if (dgv_ven.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[13].Value != null)
              {
                  fil.Show();
                  ad.lbl_msls.Text = "El Producto Ya Fue Agregado A La Lista";
                  ad.ShowDialog();
                  fil.Hide();
                              dgv_ven.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Codigo"].Value =
dgv_ven.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CodigoA"].Value.ToString();
                              return;
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              fil.Show();
                              ad.lbl_msls.Text = "El Producto Ya Fue Agregado A La Lista";
                              ad.ShowDialog();
                              fil.Hide();
                              dgv_ven.Rows.RemoveAt(dgv_ven.CurrentRow.Index);
                              return;

                          }

                      }

                      buscar_Productos(valor.Trim());
                      /* dgv_ven.Rows.RemoveAt(dgv_ven.CurrentRow.Index)*/
                      ;

                      dgv_ven.CurrentCell = dgv_ven.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
                      dgv_ven.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Selected = true;

                      Calcular();


                  }
              }

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {

              return;
          }
      }
```

Comment: Que dificultad estas teniendo?, Puedes asignar un `RepositoryItemTextEdit` a la celda 0 del `GridControl` y luego validar que cuando el EditValueChanged del `RepositoryItemTextEdit` realizas la busqueda y si obtienes resultados, asignas esos datos a las celdas correspondientes usando [GridView.SetRowCellValue(....,....,...)](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.SetRowCellValue(System.Int32-System.String-System.Object)). Hay multiples formas de lograr lo que deseas, igual puedes usar el evento `GridControl.ValidateRow` entre otros...

Comment: Gracias amigo ,a la verdad soy novato usando controles de devExpress y se me esta complicando y no se como puedo convertir mi codigo para ser usado en DevExpress :(